# Cant create notebook from github in Data science experience

Tags: data-science-experience

I recently i've tried to create a notebook in data science experience uploding it from a github repository but when i try to create i get this message.

[image]

The git repository is public and I tried with other repositories and i get the same message. Any idea if this is an actual known issue ??

Comment: Are you using the RAW version of that notebook?

Comment: If your URL does reference the RAW version (https://github.com/....ipynb?raw=true or https://raw.githubusercontent.com/....ipynb)  could you post a link to the notebook?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you are not using the **RAW** version of that notebook. That is a different URL and delivers the actual notebook. If you use the URI shown when browsing a repository, other markup is included. It results in the file not being a valid notebook, but garbage.

Comment: Thanks but I just saw that im having issues with my data science experience. I cant even create a blank notebook because a pop up comes up saying "Service not responding"

Comment: I'd contact support then @SamirChar